# Not able to read file with absolute path (to app bundle)

Tags: ios

I am trying to read files from the App bundle (and Library) directory using absolute path like this:

```
 NSString* imagePath = "/var/mobile/Applications/7AC2295E-2775-41EA-B017-AB4048A09F0C/My.app/image.jpg";
```

When I check if the file exist using

```
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath];
```

it returns TRUE but when I try to open the image with

```
  [UIImage imangeNamed:imagePath];

  it returns nil.
```

What am I doing wrong here. I am scratching my head for few hours!! please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation for `imageNamed:`. It takes a *name*, not a full path, and searches the application bundle for it. If you want to use a full path you should use another initializer method, such as `initWithContentsOfFile:`.